# Android Event Listener's initialize crashes app

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-event

I am using the AVD Emulator to run apk. I have created a simple activity, which has two buttons, however whenever I write code for any of them, the app won't start, excluding to initialize them.

If I declare the actionlistener like below (code between asterisks) it causes the apk to throw an error on start up. I have attempted to place " `android:onClick="btnLoginClicked`" in the xml, however I get the same result.

Anyone able to tell me why this is? I get the feeling I'm missing something really simple.

```
package uk.ac.aber.cs22120.fuzzyNinja.pathFinder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
//import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class ActivityLogin extends Activity {

    private Button btnLogin; 
    private ProgressBar progressBar_Login;
    //    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        progressBar_Login = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_Login);

***************************
        //btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnLoginClickListener);
***************************

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
        return true;
    }
*************************
    //private OnClickListener btnLoginClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
    //  public void onClick(View v){
    //          
    //  }
    //};
*************************
}
```

The Following is my XML for this Activity: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d91t6xqrusi1s2t/activity_login.xml

Comment: Can we have a logcat, please?

Comment: Do you want to put onclicklistener() on button click???

Comment: psyren89 - Just exported logcat twice, it won't write the file, appears it's fixed now. Tamilan worked it out, thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Declear your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);` below `super.onCreate` before **initializing** any `button`, `textview`, etc.,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        progressBar_Login = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_Login);

***************************
        //btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnLoginClickListener);
***************************        
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, straight fix, wasn't aware that would make a difference tbf. What do setContentView(R.layout.activity_Login); do? aside from set this activity to the active one?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView%28android.view.View%29 will give you a fair idea about it..

Answer (score 0):

You can always initialize the events on your views after inflating your layout in your `onCreate()` method without it your application will not be able to find the views which you are trying.

Try out the below code and set your `setcontentView()` method before initializing your views.

```
public class ActivityLogin extends Activity {

private Button btnLogin; 
private ProgressBar progressBar_Login;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    progressBar_Login = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_Login);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(btnLoginClickListener);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_login, menu);
    return true;
}

private OnClickListener btnLoginClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v){
    //your logic here. 

  }
};
```

}